# C# EF CF Select multiple queries

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

```
public class TempClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CountEntries { get; set; }
}

string sql = "select ID, count(*) as CountEntries from table1;select ID, count(*) as CountEntries from table2";

var result = _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<TempClass>(sql).ToList<TempClass>(); ???
```

Execute several commands, is that possible using EF Code First? or do you have to get them one at a time (the above then results in 2 SqlQueries.

Comment: What do you want to get from your query?

Comment: Idea was to do a transaction in the database and just get statistics from 3-4 different tables. Then the question is, do i have to do it per table or can i do it in one transaction and get 3-4 lists back with statistics? (Don't mind the SQL code above, i just want to know if its possible and how i can get several lists back into my variable)

Comment: That depends entirely on the data/relations you have.  Note that running multiple queries in the same statement is probably not the route you want to go (especially as it makes certain types of exploits easier).    Please show sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use this :

```
var query = (from s in context.table1.Take(1)
             select new
             {
                 subSetA = context.tablw1.ToList(),
                 subSetB = context.tablw2.ToList(),
             })
```